# SQL Sum Char Value

Tags: sql, oracle

for exmaple
There is any way to put these lines in one line?

```
select
SUM(Created_by) 

 from ( select
Created_by
from Employee
UNION ALL
select 
to_char('-')
from employee )
```

Comment: If you could add sample data to your question it would be helpful.

Comment: select 
SUm(ShipmentNo),
SUm(CREATED_BY) from  (select 
SUm(ShipmentNo),
SUm(CREATED_BY)

 from (select distinct
TO_NUMBER('0')  ShipmentNo,
TO_CHAR(WND.CONFIRMED_BY) CREATED_BY

from
WSH_DELIVERY_ASSIGNMENTS   UNION ALL SELECT
TO_NUMBER(rcvh.SHIPMENT_NUM) SHIPMENT_NUM,
TO_CHAR('-')

  FROM RCV_SHIPMENT_HEADERS rcvh  like this but i got error when i try to sum CHAR

Comment: That won't work. You can't apply SUM to a dash. It would help if you explained what you plan to do.

Comment: I have many data in two unions and I would like to put all in one line so i would like to calculate all values in two unions with sum or anything like that but when i try to sum TO_CHAR I got error

Comment: What is, in your opinion, result of  `1 + A + FX(3!&13?`? That's what you're trying to do.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer here.

Comment: What is, in your opinion, result of 1 + A + FX(3!&13?? That's what you're trying to do.  yes like this i would like to put all in on line

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you, please, edit the original question you posted and explain what you meant? Sample data would greatly help.